# Bottom up Hindley-Milner type inference: Applying a substitution to an implicit constraint

Tags: functional-programming, type-inference, unification, hindley-milner

I am trying to implement the 'Bottom up' type inference algorithm which can be found in [Generalizing Hindley-Milner Type Inference Algorithms](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.18.9348)

Page 6 explains how an implicit constraint is

> `t1` should be an instance of the type scheme that is obtained by generalizing type `t2` with respect to the set of monomorphic type variables `M`

However, on page 9, during the explanation of how to apply a substitution to an implicit constraints, I am told to apply a substitution to this set of monomorphic type variables. The problem is that if i have the substitution `[t1 := t2 -> t3]` then `M` is no longer a set of type variables.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: I'd go for http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ or http://cs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Jan I found out the answer in the end and added it below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got in touch with the authors of the paper and when they told me the answer I did kick myself a bit:

The substitution function has the form `S : Substitution -> a -> a` so when applying this to a set of type variables then the result will be a set of type variables.

So when applying `[t1 := t2 -> t3]` instead of replacing with `t2 -> t3` I replace with `ftv(t2 -> t3)` aka `[t2, t3]` (where `ftv` is a function to get the free type variables in a type).

Answer (score 1):

If the set of monomorphic type variables is encoded as a set of monotypes (as opposed to bare variable names) then freevars in freevars(M) on page 9 doesn't need (yet another) overloading, ditto the application of substitutions.

In this respect the typing of SOLVE seems slightly broken:  in the definition of activevars, freevars is applied to M, while in SOLVE freevars is not applied to M ("freevars(t2) - M"), and M can't possibly contain type schemes, i.e. have bound variables.  So is M a set a free variables names (no need to apply freevars before a set operation with other freevars(t)) or is it a set of monotypes (need to apply freevars)?